# SoftLayer API to know and total and available IPs in a VLAN

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer API to know and total and available IPs in a VLAN

Hello,

Which API can be used to know the total IPs and the used/usable IPs of a VLAN if I know the `VLAN ID`.

One way I could figure out is I can get subnets of a VLAN and then in subnet details I can see total and usable IPs with `"totalIpAddresses,usableIpAddressCount"` attributes . But then I will have to get sum of total and usable IPs for a VLAN since a VLAN has multiple subnets. Not sure if this is the correct way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the information for the vlan about its subnets with the total used/usable IPs, try the following Python Script.

This script will help to get the exact number of free slots from subnets inside the vlan.

```
"""
This script retrieves the Total Ip Addresses, Usable Ip Address Count and Free Slots for an specific Vlan Id

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable

# Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
username = 'set me'
apikey = 'set me'

# Define the vlan Id
vlanId = 318734

# Contact To SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=username, api_key=apikey)

# Declare an Object Mask to get additional information
object_mask = 'mask[primaryRouter,primarySubnet[datacenter[name]],subnets[billingItem, subnetType,networkIdentifier, cidr, totalIpAddresses, usableIpAddressCount, ipAddresses[ipAddress, isReserved, virtualGuest, hardware]]]'
# Declare an Object Filter to get information from specific vlan
filter = {'networkVlans': {'id': {'operation': vlanId}}}


result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkVlans(mask=object_mask, filter=filter)
x = PrettyTable(["Vlan Id", "Vlan Number", "Subnet", "Total Ip Addresses", "Usable Ip Address Count","Free Slots"])

count = 0
for vlan in result:
    for subnet in vlan['subnets']:
        for item in subnet['ipAddresses']:
            if item['isReserved'] == True:
                count = count + 1
            if 'hardware' in item:
                count = count + 1
            if 'virtualGuest' in item:
                count = count + 1
        if (subnet['usableIpAddressCount'] - count) > 0:
            if subnet['subnetType'] == 'PRIMARY' or subnet['subnetType'] == 'ADDITIONAL_PRIMARY':
                x.add_row([vlan['id'], str('%s  %s' % (vlan['primaryRouter']['hostname'], vlan['vlanNumber'])), str('%s/%s' % (subnet['networkIdentifier'], subnet['cidr'])), subnet['totalIpAddresses'], subnet['usableIpAddressCount'], (subnet['usableIpAddressCount'] - count)])
        count = 0
print(x)
```

References:
[SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following:

```
 https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/[Vlan_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[subnets[ipAddresses]]
Method: GET
```

Or,

if you want this request retrieves the `VLAN` associated with an IP address via the IP's associated subnet:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getVlanForIpAddress?objectMask=mask[id, vlanNumber,networkSpace,primaryRouter]
Method: POST
```

Json:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    "10.41.160.194"
  ]
}
```

Reference:
[getVlanForIpAddress](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getVlanForIpAddress)

Also you can see the meaning of data displayed in 'Subnet' section of above request, i.e.:

**totalIpAddresses:** The number of IP addresses contained within this subnet.

**usableIpAddressCount:**  The number of IP addresses that can be addressed within this subnet.

Comment: Hello,  I am looking for something else. This is regarding the total IPs available in a VLAN/subnet and number of Ips which are already allocated to a device or free for allocation.

Comment: The API which you have given given me the VLAN to which an IP belongs.

Comment: Please. let me review more about this :). I'll send you other update

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj, I added in the first part other request using some masks, is that you are looking for?. First we found the `subnet` associated to an specific `VLAN`, then we list the IPs related to this found `subnet`.

Comment: "totalIpAddresses": 32,
      "usableIpAddressCount": 29,                                                                      What are these parameters for?

Comment: The `"totalIpAddresses"` means `"The number of IP addresses that can be addressed within this subnet."`. When you go to "https://control.softlayer.com/network/vlans/[vlan_id]" and select a `subnet`; it will show you the associated List of ips. `"usableIpAddressCount"` means `"The number of IP addresses that can be addressed within this subnet."`. Reference: [Subnet Data Types](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet).