# The subnet specified #551994 (10.104.232.0/26) does not currently have available slots. Free up space or remove the subnet specification

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Geting this  error even if my subnet have all slots available that is :-

ipaddress in api response the flag IsReserved=false for all ipaddress

API:-
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateSubnets.json?objectMask=mask[networkVlan.privateNetworkGatewayCount,routingTypeName,%20networkVlan.primaryRouter.hostname,utilizedIpAddressCount,ipAddresses[ipAddress,%20isReserved,%20virtualGuest,%20hardware]]

Response for subnet is:-

{"broadcastAddress":"10.104.232.63","cidr":26,"gateway":"10.104.232.1","id":551994,"isCustomerOwned":false,"isCustomerRoutable":false,"modifyDate":"2018-03-01T01:51:51-06:00","netmask":"255.255.255.192","networkIdentifier":"10.104.232.0","networkVlanId":2250453,"sortOrder":"2","subnetType":"SECONDARY_ON_VLAN","totalIpAddresses":"64","usableIpAddressCount":"61","version":4,"addressSpace":"PRIVATE","ipAddresses":[{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.0","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.1","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.2","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.3","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.4","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.5","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.6","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.7","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.8","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.9","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.10","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.11","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.12","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.13","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.14","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.15","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.16","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.17","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.18","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.19","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.20","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.21","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.22","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.23","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.24","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.25","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.26","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.27","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.28","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.29","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.30","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.31","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.32","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.33","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.34","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.35","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.36","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.37","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.38","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.39","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.40","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.41","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.42","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.43","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.44","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.45","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.46","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.47","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.48","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.49","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.50","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.51","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.52","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.53","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.54","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.55","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.56","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.57","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.58","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.59","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.60","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.61","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.62","isReserved":false},{"ipAddress":"10.104.232.63","isReserved":false}],"networkVlan":{"accountId":1521909,"id":2250453,"modifyDate":"2018-01-23T05:25:01-06:00","primarySubnetId":984435,"vlanNumber":808,"privateNetworkGatewayCount":0,"primaryRouter":{"hostname":"bcr02a.ams01"}},"routingTypeName":"Portable","utilizedIpAddressCount":0}

Comment: I suggest you try through the control portal page. If the error persist I recommend you open a ticket.

Comment: Take into account only primary subnets can be assigned when ordering vsi or bare metal.

Comment: Yes it is primary subnets

Comment: Is there an another way to find out whether the subnet has free slots or not

Comment: See these two forums: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822511/api-create-a-vsi-with-a-public-subnet-fail-with-error-the-subnet-specified-1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787923/softlayer-api-to-know-and-total-and-available-ips-in-a-vlan/35799487#35799487

Comment: I have tried this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787923/softlayer-api-to-know-and-total-and-available-ips-in-a-vlan/35799487#35799487  but still i am not able to filter the subnet based on that factor ISREQUIRED,VMGUEST and HARDWARE is attached to subnet .as my api response shows that all the ipaddresses are free and there Isrequired is false ....u can see it above..

Comment: Did you try using the subnet by control portal? Because there you will see if that subnet is available to be use. You have to check too the subnet type, it seems ¨Portable¨ and not primary subnet.